# Jquery .next() Bootstrap data-provide

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

**Solved**

My script as far is:

```
<tr><td class="span1"><b><?php echo $this->getLang('UI', 49);?></b></td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-append">
             <input type="text" id="HackType_Search" name="inputType" placeholder="Type" class=" input-xlarge ajaxStatusIndicatorInput" style="margin-bottom:0px;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" rel="tooltip" title="Choose the type of the file which mostly fits." required>
                    <span class="add-on"></span>
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

When I do an ajax-call to my website to verify the data that was entered, I want to give this `<span class="add-on"></span>` the class `statusSuccessMini`. That indicates everything is correct.

Doing the call and getting results is working allright, but the interesting part is, that this:

```
 $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(idx, data) {

    if(data.bool === 'true' && data.name) {
        $('input[name='+data.name+']').next('.add-on').addClass('statusSuccessMini');
        $('input[name='+data.name+']').next('.add-on').html('.add-on');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name='+data.name+']').next('.add-on').addClass('statusWarningMini');
        i++;
    }
});
```

Will only work if there's no data-provide like this `data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"` given.

This works:

```
<tr><td class="span1"><b><?php echo $this->getLang('UI', 49);?></b></td>
<td>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="HackType_Search" name="inputType" placeholder="Type" class=" input-xlarge ajaxStatusIndicatorInput" style="margin-bottom:0px;" rel="tooltip" title="Choose the type of the file which mostly fits." required>
        <span class="add-on"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

I checked all the data, they work and I can find the input but when I try to find the span with .next() it only gets it when there's no data-provide given.

I hope you can help me, any suggestion is appreciated :)

**Edit: FF Code Inspector showed me this:**

```
<div class="input-append">

<input id="Game_Search" class="input-xlarge ajaxStatusIndicatorInput" type="text" required="" title="" rel="tooltip" style="margin-bottom:0px;" data-items="4" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Game" name="inputGameID" data-original-title="Choose the game the file works with."></input>
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" style="top: 454px; left: 516.7px; display: none;">
    <li class="active" data-value="Silkroad Online"></li>
    <li data-value="Crysis 2"></li>
    <li data-value="Planetside 2"></li>
    <li data-value="Counter-Strike 1.6"></li>
</ul>
<span class="add-on"></span>
</div>
```

So the Bootstrap Typeahead is inserting a list into the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[name= + data.name + ']').parent().find('.add-on').addClass('statusWarningMini');
```

See Documentation: [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) / [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[Here's a working Demo (via jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/3R22y/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Works very well :>